# How to use different Service name in the Oracle JDBC long TNSNAME style URL with multiple servers

Tags: oracle, url, jdbc, cluster-computing, tnsnames

I have a problem when I try to connect DB server with JDBC long TNSNAME style URL. We have two Oracle cluster servers. And here is my TNSNAME style URL.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
  (LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS_LIST=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1250))
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2)(PORT=1250))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA=
    (SERVICE_NAME= DEV1)
  )
)
```

My problem is when our DBA create the database, he used different service names for the host1 and host2. host1 is DEV1 and host2 is DEV2_B, and seems it cannot work if I switch the host sequence. Like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
  (LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS_LIST=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2)(PORT=1250)) /*host2 now come first, it would be cause connect failure.*/
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1250))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA=
    (SERVICE_NAME= DEV1)
  )
)
```

I think under this situation, Fail over and load balance are useless. My question is, how to set the service_name separately in my URL? (Those two DB also use different SID. DEVA and DEVB)
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Your database is using Oracle RAC or standby?

Comment: if rac, did the dba setup the remote_listener param so the nodes register with the remote listener?  if setup properly, either node should be able to used in your jdbc connection.  i would poke your dba for assistance

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: @turbanoff, not sure which one, how can I know?

Comment: if you use RAC, then DB have one common SID/SERVICE_NAME. Standby is two different databases, synchronized with each other. Best way to know what is used is to ask your DBA.

Answer (score 1):

```
(DESCRIPTION_LIST=
            (FAILOVER=true)
            (LOAD_BALANCE=false)
            (DESCRIPTION=
            (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=TEST_DB) (PORT=1521))
            (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME=saibal)))             
            (DESCRIPTION=
            (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=MY_DB) (PORT=1521))
            (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME= test_saibal))
)
```

Comment: You can make this answer better by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39259947/edit) to explain how does it work.